# CMake can't find IMPORTED library

Tags: cmake

In `foo/CMakeLists.txt`, based on [this](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-June/022256.html) and [this](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets), I have the following

```
SET (EXTERNAL_LIB_ROOT "../../external_libs/")

ADD_LIBRARY (avcodec-debug STATIC IMPORTED)

SET_PROPERTY (
    TARGET avcodec-debug PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${EXTERNAL_LIB_ROOT}/libavcodec-0.8.10.a)
```

In `bar/CMakeLists.txt` I have this:

```
# old way uses system libraries
#TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (bar avformat avcodec avutil)

# new way uses local debug builds
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (bar avformat avcodec-debug avutil)
```

When I run `make` I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavcodec-debug
```

If I revert to the old way, build, touch `foo/CMakeLists.txt` and rebuild, CMake's configuration output indicates that avcodec-debug *is* being found by the build system.

So why can't I add it as a dependency?

Comment: What's the relationship between `foo/CMakeLists.txt` and `bar/CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(foo)` and `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(bar)` appear in the top-level CMakeLists.txt

Comment: You should add that to the question, it's important.

Comment: The visibility rules are different, but not knowing that, it isn't important at all given what I already "know" about visibility rules.

Comment: That's why I said "you should add that" and not "you should have added that." I just meant that it will make the question more complete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imported targets do not follow the same visibility rules as non-imported targets. While non-imported targets are global (visible and accessible from anywhere after they're defined), imported targets are only visible in the `CMakeLists.txt` where they are defined and below (in directories added by `add_subdirectory()` in this defining CMakeList).

Since `foo` is a sibling of `bar` in your case, the target name `avcodec-debug` is not visible inside `bar/CMakeLists.txt`, so it's treated as a normal library name.

It's generally preferred to define imported targets in files you include rather than in their own projects. So change (or extract the relevant parts of) `foo/CMakeLists.txt` into `foo/avcodec.cmake` and then in the top-level CMakeList, replace

```
add_subdirectory(foo)
```

with

```
include(foo/avcodec.cmake)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not there yet. I created trunk/external/libav.cmake which imports ../../external_libs/libav*.a (relative to trunk/external, external_libs/ is a sibling of trunk/) and trunk/foo/bar/CMakeLists has `include(../../external/libav.cmake)` but it complains: "No rule to make target `../../external_libs/libavcodec-0.8.10.a'" ... any idea?

Comment: Furthermore, if I change the import path to `../external_libs/lbav*` then CMake configuration succeeds (which makes no sense to me) but g++ fails to find the library.

Comment: I suggest using explicit path prefixes such as `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` instead of relying on relative paths, especially when those start with `..`.

Comment: To elaborate on @Angew's comment above, if an included file uses code to set a variable that is used in an including file, like `set(MY_FILE "../foobar.c")`, the location of foobar.c is interpreted relative to the including file's location.  On the other hand, `set(MY_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../foobar.c")` would expand the value of CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR when MY_FILE is set, so it will be correct no matter where the value of MY_FILE is used.

Answer (score 14):

As it mentioned above by Angew the visibility for imported library differs, though you can extend it using `GLOBAL` modifier. It might be enough for you to modify `add_library` call next way:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(avcodec-debug STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
```